# Removing Material warning from the browser console

Tags: angular, angular-material

getting warning in my browser console:

> DEPRECATED: DI is instantiating a token "MatCarouselHammerConfig" that inherits its @Injectable decorator but does not provide one itself.
> This will become an error in v10. Please add @Injectable() to the "MatCarouselHammerConfig" class.

i went to node_modules/@ngmodule/material-carousel/esm5/lib/carousel.module.js

```
 * @fileoverview added by tsickle
 * @suppress {checkTypes,extraRequire,missingReturn,unusedPrivateMembers,uselessCode} checked by tsc
 */
import * as tslib_1 from "tslib";
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCarouselComponent } from './carousel.component';
import { MatCarouselSlideComponent } from './carousel-slide/carousel-slide.component';
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10541#issuecomment-300761387
var
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10541#issuecomment-300761387
MatCarouselHammerConfig = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    tslib_1.__extends(MatCarouselHammerConfig, _super);
    function MatCarouselHammerConfig() {
        var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        _this.overrides = {
            pinch: { enable: false },
            rotate: { enable: false }
        };
        return _this;
    }
    return MatCarouselHammerConfig;
}(HammerGestureConfig));
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10541#issuecomment-300761387
export { MatCarouselHammerConfig };
if (false) {
    /** @type {?} */
    MatCarouselHammerConfig.prototype.overrides;
}
var MatCarouselModule = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MatCarouselModule() {
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    MatCarouselModule.forRoot = /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    function () {
        return {
            ngModule: MatCarouselModule,
            providers: [
                { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MatCarouselHammerConfig }
            ]
        };
    };
    MatCarouselModule.decorators = [
        { type: NgModule, args: [{
                    declarations: [MatCarouselComponent, MatCarouselSlideComponent],
                    imports: [CommonModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule],
                    exports: [MatCarouselComponent, MatCarouselSlideComponent]
                },] }
    ];
    return MatCarouselModule;
}());
export { MatCarouselModule };
```

How to add @Injectable() decorator in this js file.??
i need to resolve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue in my angular 10 project, it seems to be Ivy is causing this problem, this plugin need to be updated to support Ivy, If you found any solution please let me know.

Github issue is archived but still open on the project github page: https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/material2-carousel/issues/59